# Moving Image in ScrollViewer (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, winrt-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I've got a `Image` in `Scrollviewer`...

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Scrollster" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="4"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ManipulationMode="All">
    <Image x:Name="Img" Source="{x:Bind ImgSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" PointerPressed="Img_PointerPressed"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to move Image when I drag image with Mouse Pointer!

I tried:

```
private void Img_PointerPressed(object sender,PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var p = e.Pointer;
}
```

but I can't get pointer position to change scrollviewer postion.

What's wrong with my code? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ManipulationMode` should be set on the `Img` control instead. Also, you probably want to specify the exact modes you want rather than `All` to prevent unnecessary gesture handling.

```
<Image x:Name="Img" Source="{x:Bind ImgSource}" Width="150" Height="150" Stretch="UniformToFill" 
       ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY"
       ManipulationStarted="Img_ManipulationStarted"
       ManipulationDelta="Img_ManipulationDelta"
       ManipulationCompleted="Img_ManipulationCompleted">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="Transform" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

From your description above, I think turning on both `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` should be sufficient. Then you will need to handle manipulation events like `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationCompleted`.

Most of your logic should be done in `ManipulationDelta` event which will be fired multiple times during the progression of the panning. It's where you get the `X` and `Y` positions and set them accordingly.

Here is a simple sample for this.

```
void Img_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // dim the image while panning
    this.Img.Opacity = 0.4;
}

void Img_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    this.Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}

void Img_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // reset the Opacity
    this.Img.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: Works fine but Now in touch mode (table and mobile) I can't pinch to zoom in and out ! what's the problem? Should I ask it in a new topic?

Comment: I believe you need to turn on `ManipulationModes.Scale` and handle `this.Transform.ScaleX` and `this.Transform.ScaleY` manually. Or maybe, when there are more than one contacts, disable `ManipulationMode` and let the system handle the zoom in/out.

Comment: Now I know how to fix it : Adding System to ManipulationMode will fix it. I mean : `ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY, System"`

Comment: Yes, as the default mode is System. So when I changed to TranslateX n TranslateY, I disabled all the systems auto handling. :p

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day!