# drag and drop the images on canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have used the following code to display the images on canvas

```
void Stickers1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selecteditem = e.AddedItems[0] as StickersImageListModel;
    {
        Stickers1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Image imageitem = new Image();
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(selecteditem.Imageurl, UriKind.Absolute));
        imageitem.Source = image;
        my_canvas.Children.Add(imageitem);
        imageitem.AllowDrop = true;
    }
    my_canvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

now i want to drag and drop these images on my canvas please help me to do this and I tried this

```
private Image _imageUrl;
public Image Imageurl
{
    get { return _imageUrl; }
    set { _imageUrl = value; }
}

private void my_canvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Position.X > Canvas.GetLeft(Imageurl) && e.Position.X < Canvas.GetLeft(Imageurl) + Imageurl.Width)
       || (e.Position.Y > Canvas.GetTop(Imageurl) && e.Position.Y < Canvas.GetTop(Imageurl) + Imageurl.Height))
    {
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Imageurl, e.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(Imageurl, e.Position.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting Imageurl?

Comment: Have you gone through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221706/drag-drop-and-resize-images-on-canvas