# UWP inkCanvas infinite surface same as microsoft whiteboard application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store, inkcanvas, whiteboard

I saw Microsoft's whiteboard today and I like the base inkCanvas(it's my guess) control of it. and I decide to create a control in UWP app using inkCanvas which behaves similar as Microsoft's whiteboard UWP application. [Microsoft UWP Whiteboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-whiteboard-preview/9mspc6mp8fm4) 
 - My goal is as below

1. It should add width & scroll on right side if inkCanvas has any shape draw near right side. I tried below code it actully working but not scrolling the way in microsoft's whiteboard is working.

> ```
> var right = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Right;
>         if (right > inkCanvas.ActualWidth - 400)
>         {
>             inkCanvas.Width = right + 400;
>         }
> ```

2. Similar for bottom side of inkCanvas to increase height.

> ```
> var bottom = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Bottom;
>             if (bottom > inkCanvas.ActualHeight - 400)
>             {
>                 grdCan.Height = bottom + 400;
>             }
> ```

The problem is same it is not getting scroll automatically.

Also for adding space on left side I have used the flowcontrol property of inkCanvas which is working fine, but for adding space in "Top" position I have no solution.

any help or direction would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Update: Code

> ```
> <Grid>
>             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
>             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>             <InkToolbar Grid.Row="0" 
>                         Margin="10"
>                         x:Name="inkToolbar" 
>                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
>                         TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}">
>             </InkToolbar>
>             <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
>                           x:Name="scrollViewer" 
>                           ZoomMode="Enabled" 
>                           MinZoomFactor="1" 
>                           MaxZoomFactor="20"
>                           VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
>                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
>                           HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
>                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
>                 <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ViewportHeight}"
>                             Width="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ViewportWidth}">
>                     <Canvas x:Name="recognitionCanvas"/>
>                     <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"/>
>                 </Grid>
>             </ScrollViewer>
>         </Grid>
> ```

Comment: Does the `inkCanvas` placed in the `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes!

Comment: Show more xaml code or simple sample.

Comment: added my actual code. :)

Comment: Do you want to realize mouse drag scroll in the ScrollViewer?

Comment: Probably yes! Actually I want to replicate the behavior of Microsoft's Whiteboard surface on which we can draw. If you get chance to install, then kindly install it. So  I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not.

Comment: I found you have realize partial function such as extend inkCanvas  area, but it can't scroll with muse drag, aright?

Comment: Did you find Microsoft Whiteboard has Finger linking button?

Comment: Yes! I have it in toolbar. I have added custom button where I am setting the inputdevicetype as below - 
`if (touchEnableDisable.IsChecked == false)
            {
                inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes |= CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
            }
            else
            {
                inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes &= ~CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
            }`

Comment: Please refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900806/7254781).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168910/discussion-between-ganesh-prakash-mahajan-and-nico-zhu-msft).